# Validating any object schema depending on validity of another object schema in yup

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I used yup schema with react-hook-form, when submitting form I need to show required fields below input fields. We can use when() validating conditionally only for some field's value.

I have an object with 2 fields (A and B), their values are also object. In my case field B field must be validated when A field is valid. Is it possible in yup?